# For Loops (C++)

Tags: c++

**Assignment:**

The program should ask the user to enter a positive number and display all numbers from 1 to the input value. If the number is not positive, an error message should show up asking the user to re - enter the number.

**My specific problem:**

For my program, if the user enters an incorrect number and then re - enters a positive number, it does not display all the numbers from 1 to the input value. The program just ends.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int userChoice;
int i = 1;

cout << "Enter a positive integer" << endl;
cin >> userChoice;

if (userChoice > 0)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= userChoice; i++)
    {
        cout << "Loop 1:" << endl;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
else if (userChoice < 0)
    cout << "Please re - enter" << endl;
cin >> userChoice;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the user enters a negative number, you simply re-ask the number without doing anything else.

Comment: You need some kind of retry loop here, going round until the user enters a valid number. Perhaps a `while` loop at the top, with the behaviour `while(the user entered bad input) { ask again }`.

Comment: It would be best to restructure this program slightly. First step: Keep requesting user input until a positive number has been entered. Second step: Print out the numbers from 1 to the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need some sort of loop at the top of your program, that keeps asking for input until the user provides something valid. It looks like a homework assignment, so I will provide pseudo-code, not something exact:

```
std::cout << "Enter a number:\n";
std::cin >> choice;
while (choice wasn't valid) { // 1
    tell the user something went wrong // 2
    ask again for input in basically the same way as above // 3
}
// after this, go ahead with your for loop
```

It is actually possible to avoid the duplication here for step 3, but I worry that might be a little confusing for you, so one duplicated line really isn't such a big problem.

---

As an aside, you may wish to reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2619). (Disclaimer - these are opinions, not hard facts).